# Bootstrap DateTimePicker returning wrong Time with minDate and maxDate

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hello I am trying to make bootstrap datetimepicker plugin work correctly with minDate and maxDate, this is my code:

```
var $el                      = $('#dateFrom');
var baseDate                = "2018-11-20";
var defaultDate             = moment(baseDate + " 13:30:00");
var min                     = moment(baseDate + " 08:00:00");
var max                     = moment(baseDate + " 22:00:00");

if($el.data('DateTimePicker')){ //function needs to reset it on each call
    $el.data('DateTimePicker').destroy();
}

$el.val(defaultDate.format("HH:mm"));

var config = {
  format:"HH:mm",
  defaultDate:defaultDate,
  minDate:min,
  maxDate:max
}

$el.datetimepicker(config);
```

The problem here is it defaults the time to the minDate instead of setting it to the defaultDate, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/imurphy/bte731ux/38/

Comment: Per the documentation: "Will override defaultDate and useCurrent if either of these settings are the **same day** since both options are invalid according to the rules you've selected." (emphasis mine). Are you trying to only allow a time range for a specific date?

Comment: Yes I am trying to allow only a specific time range regardless of the date I only care about the time here

Comment: I believe you're after `disabledTimeIntervals`, then: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disabledtimeintervals

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: @TiesonT. thank you it looks like the right way to go, the only thing is if you put a range from 0 to 8 and 22 to 24 you are still able to select the "0" hour, any thought to also disable 0?

Comment: Not sure. That seems like a bug, if I'm being honest. If you just use the up/down arrows, it won't allow that time, but you can click the hour and select it. I'd have to dig into the code to see why.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the library needs to updated, per moment: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/06-is-between/ - the range check is exclusive, so there's no way to disable that zero hour. It's a simple fix, though - let me see if I can get a pull-request pushed in. Which version of the datetimepicker are you using?

Comment: If you don't mind using an "unofficial" version, this seems to work: https://gist.github.com/tiesont/97d9e8b5ac5b0d780ba872422fb5525c - it's based on a version of datetimepicker that was tweaked to work with Bootstrap 4: https://github.com/pingcheng/bootstrap4-datetimepicker. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcrb2xsm/3/

Comment: If you're curious, this is the only change that seems to be necessary: https://gist.github.com/tiesont/97d9e8b5ac5b0d780ba872422fb5525c#file-bootstrap-datetimepicker-js-L562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to accomplish what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/gcrb2xsm/

```
var $el          = $('#dateFrom');
var baseDate     = "2018-11-20";
var defaultDate  = moment(baseDate + " 13:30:00");

if($el.data('DateTimePicker')){
    $el.data('DateTimePicker').destroy();
}

$el.val(defaultDate.format("HH:mm"));
$('#should').text("Initian value should be " + defaultDate.format("HH:mm"));

var config = {
  format:"HH:mm",
  defaultDate:defaultDate,
  disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 8 })], [moment({ h: 22 }), moment({ h: 24 })]]
}

$el.datetimepicker(config);
```

Basically, the [disabledTimeIntervals](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disabledtimeintervals) is the option to use when trying to limit the time selection to a specific time range. You would add a pair of start and stop times for each range to **exclude**. So, the values shown above are:

```
[
    [moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 8 })] /* disable from midnight to 8 AM */, 
    [moment({ h: 22 }), moment({ h: 24 }) /* disable from 10 PM to midnight */]
]
```

Comment: Thanks it works, although 0 hours is still selectable, any idea to also disable it?